# Polymorphism and Dependency Injection, how to select child class without instantiating it

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, polymorphism, factory

With DI, the approach I have always used is constructor injection.  Also with DI, the dependency class is injected into the calling class, there is no need to instantiated the dependency class.

Consider this code below, I need to determine which concrete class to use.  How do I select the proper concrete class without manually instantiating the class (since with DI, the injector does it for you)?  The code is all handwritten, excuse any typo :)

```
public interface IMyInterface
    {
        void DoSomething();
    }

public class SuperClass : IMyInterface
{
    private DependencyClass _dependency;
    public SuperClass(DependencyClass dependency)
    {
         _dependency = dependency;
    }

    public abstract void DoSomething();

}

public class ChildClassCommon : SuperClass
{
    private DependencyClass _dependency;
    public ChildClassCommon(DependencyClass dependency)
    {
         _dependency = dependency;
    }

    public override void DoSomething()
    {
    }
}

public class ChildClassSpecial : SuperClass
{
    private DependencyClass _dependency;
    public ChildClassSpecial(DependencyClass dependency)
    {
         _dependency = dependency;
    }

    public override void DoSomething()
    {
    }
}


public class Main()
{
    private IMyInterface _myClass;

    public Main(IMyInterface myClass)
    {
        _myClass = myClass;
    }

    public void Selector(string recordType)
    {
        if(recordType == "Common")
        {
             // without DI, i would normally just do a new here to 
             // instantiate the concrete class, but with DI, I shouldnt be
             // instantiating a new instance, but how do I select which
             // concrete class to use?
            _myClass = new ChildClassCommon(DependencyClass dependency);
        }
        else if (recordType == "Special")
        {
            _myClass = new ChildClassSpecial(DependencyClass dependency);
        }

        _myClass.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does it mean to select a class but ain't instantiating it?

Comment: With dependency injection, the dependency is injected into the class the requires it, there is no need to instantiate it, the injector does it for you.

Comment: When applying DI, it's not suddenly _forbidden_ to `new` up classes. However, we try to centralize the creation of these classes to a single place in the application. This location is called the [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/). Your main seems to me the Composition Root of your application, so it’s perfectly safe, and sane, to new up instances there. If `Main` is not the start-up path of your application, creation should be moved to that location.

Answer (score 2):

You can register all your implemented class and factory class. After than you can resolve factory class. When you have factory class, you generate desired object with certain generate rule.

I use `Autofac` for DI tool in this example

```
class Program
{
    public class DependencyClass { }

    public interface IMyInterface
    {
        void DoSomething();
    }

    public abstract class SuperClass : IMyInterface
    {
        protected DependencyClass _dependency;
        public SuperClass(DependencyClass dependency)
        {
            _dependency = dependency;
        }

        abstract public void DoSomething();
    }

    public class ChildClassCommon : SuperClass
    {
        public ChildClassCommon(DependencyClass dependency) : base(dependency){}

        public override void DoSomething(){}
    }

    public class ChildClassSpecial : SuperClass
    {
        public ChildClassSpecial(DependencyClass dependency) : base(dependency){}

        public override void DoSomething(){}
    }

    public class MyInterfaceFactory
    {
        private IEnumerable<IMyInterface> _myInterfaces;
        public MyInterfaceFactory(IEnumerable<IMyInterface> myInterfaces)
        {
            _myInterfaces = myInterfaces;
        }

        public IMyInterface Generate(string rule)
        {
            IMyInterface myObject;
            if (rule == "a")
                myObject = _myInterfaces.First(x => x is ChildClassCommon);
            else
                myObject = _myInterfaces.First(x => x is ChildClassSpecial);
            return myObject;
        }
    }

    // Injection run in this
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<DependencyClass>().AsSelf();


        builder.RegisterType<MyInterfaceFactory>().AsSelf();

        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        builder
            .RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
            .AssignableTo<IMyInterface>()
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();

        var container = builder.Build();

        var factory = container.Resolve<MyInterfaceFactory>();
        IMyInterface myInterface = factory.Generate("a");

        Console.WriteLine(myInterface.GetType());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adem, trying to run your code.  What is ContainerBuilder?  Code looks more complicated than I'd like, is there really no other way?

Comment: ContainerBuilder come from Autofac nuget packages. I register all class with it (factoryclass, dependencyclass, all IMyInterfaces). After this point I create a container via containerBuilder.  When I resolve factory class, all dependencies will be searched in container and inject into factory. I try to implement factory pattern with DI tools

Comment: Thanks again Adem.  I havent used autofac but your code seems useful.  I think I was spacing out and forgot I could just cast the interface to the concrete type, me dork :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood u well, but if u don't want to instantiate a class and u want to use it, maybe try with reflection? U can get specified class and then invoke it's methods.

Answer (score 0):

If I've read this correctly, then `typeof()` would be an option to reference your concrete type if you did not want to instantiate the object at that time.

```
public static Type Selector(string recordType)
{
        Type concreteType;

        switch (recordType)
        {
            case "Common":
                concreteType = typeof(ChildClassCommon);
                break;
            case "Special":
                concreteType = typeof(ChildClassSpecial);
                break;
            default:
                concreteType = null;
                break;
        }

        return concreteType;
}
```

Understand though, at some point you would need to instantiate the object to be able to use within your application. So with the example above, to instantiate, you could use [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) with your DI parameter like so:

```
var type = Selector("Common");
var myObject = (IMyInterface) Activator.CreateInstance(type, new object[] { dependency });
```

MSDN:

[`typeof()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/typeof)

[`Type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Thank you kitson88.  But with dependency injection, the injector instantiates the class there is no need to manually instantiate it.

Comment: Fully aware of what DI is. So really the problem was that you were unsure on how to cast an object to its type? I wish your question was clearer.

Answer (score -1):

I am an idiot, I can easily just cast it.  Answered my own question while watching TV :D

```
if(recordType == "Common")
        {

            ((ChildClassCommon)_myClass).DoSomething();
        }
        else if (recordType == "Special")
        {
            ((ChildClassSpecial)_myClass).DoSomething();
        }
```

Comment: You're going to get an invalid cast when you call `Selector` with a different `recordType` than the local `_myClass` is able to be cast to. The point of polymorphism is that you shouldn't need to know implementation details.